# Летающий блок между секциями

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите как сделать блок под номером 2

[image: изображение]

Comment: http://rgho.st/6fzQhFBh8
Вот пример

Comment: Опять imgur сдох...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например вот так:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.one {
  background: green;
  height: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.two {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: -100px auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.three {
  background: yellow;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class=one></div>
<div class=two></div>
<div class=three></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
body {
margin:0;
}

#block1 {
background:orange;
height:50vh;
position:relative;

}
#block2 {
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
position:absolute;
width: 80vw;
left:50%;
height:33.333vh;
top:100%;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
color:#fff;
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size:2em;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
#block3 {
background:#fb0;
height:50vh;

}
```

```html
<div id="block1">
<div id="block2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>

</div>
<div id="block3"></div>
```